# PHP/mysqli undefined variable/empty property error

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting the error "Undefined variable: conn" and "Cannot access empty property" when trying to return the database object $conn. The database connection is working, however. Is there a better way to return a database object than $this->$conn;?

```
class database {

    private $host = "xxxx";
    private $database = "xxxx";
    private $user = "xxxx";
    private $password = "xxxx";

    public $conn = "";

    function db_connect() {
        try {
            $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
            $conn;
            echo "Connected to database";
            echo "<br>";
            return $conn;
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'Connection Failed:';
            echo "<br>";
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
}

public function __construct(){
    $this->db_connect();
    return $this->$conn;
}
```

Comment: you have this line `$conn` - and php you have to assign/acces to `$this->conn`. not `$this->$conn`.

Comment: Hard coding database credentials is a bad idea, you should parse them into the constructor when initializing the class & you should look to remove the `echos` after a successful connection. You should only print/log errors, unnecessary output will produce unexpected displays

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
```

should be:

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
```

You should remove the line:

```
return $this->$conn;
```

First of all, constructors shouldn't return anything (PHP automatically returns the new object). Second, it should be `$this->conn` (with no `$` before `conn`).

Finally, the line:

```
$conn;
```

is both wrong and serves no purpose. Get rid of it.